# How can I pass the array element to a function

Tags: php, html

I have a php code where  it fetches data from the database

I used this kind of code because it needs to be encoded in JSON and called by an AJAX request.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
$data[] = array(                          
      "level"=>$whatTeam($row['level'])
   );
}
```

The thing is I want to create a function to display a much detailed value to the HTML because the values from the `$row['level']` are just keywords.

Example Value from that is "l2" but I want to display it as "Primary Leader in HTML/Table"

This is the function,

```
$whatLevel = function ($rows){ ##this is the thing that I'm asking about,
            $l1 = "Primary";   ## if it is the right way to do that
            $l2 = "Primary 12";
            $l3 = "144 Leader";
            $l4 = "1728 Leader";
            $l5 = "20,736 Leader";

            if($rows == "11"){
                return ucwords($l1);
            }else if($rows  == "l2"){
                return ucwords($l2);
            }else if($rows  == "l3"){
                return ucwords($l3);
            }else if($rows  == "l4"){
                return ucwords($l4);
            }else if($rows  == "l5"){
                return ucwords($l5);
            }
};
```

I'm not even sure if this is the right way, I'm exploring about it, is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Why not use PDO? It would be much easier to do with PDO. Is there a reason why you are still using mysqli?

Comment: later on, I will try using PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function or do it in the main code.  Either way just use an array:

```
$levels = ["l1" => "Primary", "l2" => "Primary 12", "l3" => "144 Leader",
           "l4" => "1728 Leader", "l5" => "20,736 Leader"];
```

Then:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
    $data[] = "level" => $levels[$row['level']];
}
```

To use a function:

```
$whatLevel = function($level) {
                 $levels = ["l1" => "Primary", "l2" => "Primary 12", 
                            "l3" => "144 Leader", "l4" => "1728 Leader", 
                            "l5" => "20,736 Leader"];

                 return $levels[$level];
             };
```

Then:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
    $data[] = "level" => $whatLevel($row['level']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [mysqli_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to return an array of all rows that match your sql

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($empRecords);
```